# Showing left side zeros formating strings - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, chronometer

I am trying to implement a chronometer on my app, but the left side zeros won't show up.
Do you know any way to make them default?

Here's what I am trying:

```
self.text.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.0d:%2.0d:%1.0d", minute, second, decimals];
```

Here's what I really see:

```
2014-01-04 15:55:06.462 appchrono[17556:70b]   :3:2
2014-01-04 15:55:06.562 appchrono[17556:70b]   :3:3
```

Here's what I want it to be:

```
2014-01-04 15:55:06.462 appchrono[17556:70b]   00:03:2
2014-01-04 15:55:06.562 appchrono[17556:70b]   00:03:3
```

Any help?
Thank you!

Comment: did you initialized the minute ?

Comment: Stackoverflow search didn't return this topic to me at that time.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close:

```
 self.text.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", minute, second, decimals];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `%-2.2d`. This tells the formatter to prefix zeroes.

Comment: May not make sense, but it works.

Comment: I just tried this and to my surprise this does actually give the right result. However, the more correct format would be `%02d`. The fact that `%-2.2d` actually works is pretty strange on very non-obvious.

Comment: You are very right. But I just remembered this from my printf days (1985...). In those day %02 usually did not work (depending on the actual OS being used), so we used the other.